# reusable UI in android app

Tags: android, interface

I am working on android app where I am thinking to develop reusable UI interface. How it can be developed and included in my .xml's

Here I want to develop a progress bar with my image and it will be display on some .xml's.
Please provide any code help.

I am a new in this field.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<Include>` xml tag within your layout xml,

read this :)
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Comment: Nice tip, I didn't know we could do that

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use styles and themes. [Check this out](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can either build custom (compound) views, look at [Building Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).
Or you can use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). Fragments are new in Honeycomb (Android 3.0), but there is a compatibility library that adds fragment support to lower android versions (can be found in your `ANDROID_SDK/extras/android` folder). Or you can mix both of course.